# Time and space complexity for printing Fibonacci series using recursion and loop

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory, fibonacci

What is the time and Space complexity (Big-O notation) for printing Fibonacci series using recursion and loop? There is an loop used to print the Fibonacci numbers does that also included while calculating time and space complexity?

Is my analysis below correct?

#### Using Recursion

```
public int printFibonacciSeries(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    return printFibonacciSeries(n - 1) + printFibonacciSeries(n - 2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    FibonacciSeries fibonacciSeries = new FibonacciSeries();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("i=" + i + " and "  + fibonacciSeries.printFibonacciSeries(i));
    }
}
```

My analysis:

- **Time Complexity:** *O*(*n* 2<sup>*n*</sup>) - since for all *n* values the Fibonacci is calculated (calculating *n*th Fibonacci is 2<sup>*n*</sup>)
- **Space Complexity:** *O*(1) - recursive call are added to stack but then once the execution is completed the value are delete from stack

#### Using Loop

```
public void printFibonacciSeriesWithLoop(int n) {
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i <= 1) {
            arr[i] = i;
        } else {
            arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];
        }
    }
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    FibonacciSeries fibonacciSeries = new FibonacciSeries();
    fibonacciSeries.printFibonacciSeriesWithLoop(i);
}
```

My analysis:

- **Time Complexity:** *O*(*n* + *n*) or *O*(2*n*) ⟹ *O*(*n*) - the first *O*(*n*) is for calculating and another *O*(*n*) for printing, so 2*n*, but drop the constant
- **Space Complexity:** *O*(*n*) - *n* values are stored in the array

Comment: Neither can be O(1) space complexity. Recursion rules it out for the first, and `new int[n]` rules it out for the second.

Comment: It would take more time than I have to write a complete answer, so the short version: the space complexity of the recursive solution is O(n). Space complexity measures how much space is needed to run the algorithm, not how much is used after it returns. Knowing it's O(n) means the bigger the numbers are, the larger a call stack you'll need to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: (cont'd) The time complexity of O(n 2^n) is correct, though FYI it's not a tight upper bound. The math is pretty complicated if you want a tight upper bound; it involves the [golden ratio](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-recursive-fibonacci-program/) and some gnarly algebra it's probably not worth getting into.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better as a comment, but since I dont have enough rep, here goes -

https://youtu.be/_JtPhF8MshA?t=219 you can see here how the recursive implementation takes space O(n) and not O(1) because the recursive tree is built all the way before they are all added and closed down!

(Note - the timestamp in the linked video shows the diagram for Fac(n) function but later ahead in the video Fib function is explained too but since there is no diagram there, this is attached)